# Binary search of line number

Tags: c++, file, search

I have a very long file, in which it can be assumed (if it helps) every line of which has the same format.  I want to read a specific line of the file.    Is it possible in C++ to move the pointer to that line via a binary search instead of starting at the top of the file and reading line by line and counting lines?  That is, is it possible to access some  line_of_file pointer and move it by binary search?  If not in C++, is this task possible in assembly language or some other language?

Comment: Asking "is it possible?" always makes me tempted to answer "Yes". Can you be more specific about what code you currently have, and where you're stuck? Ideally, include a simplified example of the file format so that you have a [mre] that other people can test their suggested answers against.

Comment: See `std::seekp`, `std::seekg` in your favorite reference.  Works best when records are all the same size.  Also see `std::tellp` and `std::tellg`.

Comment: Personally I'd use fseek to get to the middle of the file and read f/w or back (as you choose) to a line terminator. Use this as the start point to read a line and then decide which way in the file to fseek (back if you've gone past) and re-try. Binary search will rely on the fact that the file is sorted.

Comment: It's possible but only if the line length is equal for every line. You said the format is the same, but that doesn't mean exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot usefully use binary search to find a line by line number in a text file, because text files are not indexed by line number. In other words, there is no way to figure out the line number of a given offset in the file other than starting at the beginning, reading every character, and counting the number of new line characters.

There is only one exception, and in that case binary search won't help you either. If every line in the file is the exact same length, then you can find the offset of a specific line by multiplying that length by the line number (using 0 as the number of the first line). Don't forget to include the newline character in the line length. You can use `istream::seekg` or `ostream::seekp` to position the next input or output operation, respectively. (You need to use the two-argument version. Some other warnings apply on platforms which translate newline characters to multicharacter sequences; here's looking at you, windows.)